# Laravel behind reverse proxy not on standard ports

Tags: laravel, https, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I need to publish a Laravel application behind a reverse proxy.
I was able to setup the nginx-based Laravel server and add the reverse proxy address to the TrustProxies configuration (Fideloper).
However, the reverse proxy is running on a non-standard port and Laravel is picking it up, messing up with it.
This is my configuration:

External site on 443 <-> reverse proxy on, say, 999 <-> nginx on 80

Laravel keep generating each URL with the 999 port appended to it.
If I go to

https://my.external.domain/mylaravelapp/

I see Laravel generating in response:

https://my.external.domain:999/mylaravelapp/foo/bar

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by removing, at the proxy level, the X-Forwarded-Port header which was added to the request by default.